# Is there a keybind to close object menus?

Tags: pc, lego-worlds

In Lego Worlds, various tools such as the Discovery Tool can allow the user to access a grid-style menu that provide a variety of objects or other options. These menus can be accessed by pressing and holding tab on the PC. However, I've yet to determine how to close the menus outside of using the mouse to click the "return" button in the top-left corner of the screen. Additionally, I've been unable to find an option anywhere that allows me to set key binds. I'm finding that using the keyboard for many things, including accessing these menus, and then having to drag the mouse clear across the screen to close these menus to be an annoyance.

Is there a keybind or other keyboard shortcut to close these grid-style object menus, or a way to set one if none exists?